# How to get translated names from database using ajax in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am creating tag's input where somebody can write tag. In both languages of course. But the problem is that I can't translate them. I do not know how to do it. Can you help me? Here's my code:

JS:

```
suggestion: function(data) {
              return '<li class="list-group-item">' + "@lang('" + "main." + data.name + "')" + '</li>'
            }
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'api','middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('find', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
        $keyword = $request->input('keyword');
        Log::info($keyword);
        $positions = DB::table('positions')->where('name','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                  ->select('positions.id','positions.name','positions.display')
                  ->get();
        return json_encode($positions);
    })->name('api.positions');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is by having multiple column in your datase :

• name_en

• name_fr

• name_es

and then

check your targeted local :

```
$local = 'en';

$positions = DB::table('positions')->where('name_'. 
$local,'like','%'.$keyword.'%')
              ->select('positions.id','positions.name_' . $local .' as 
name' ,'positions.display')
              ->get();
```